# How to enable cross domain calls for self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, ajax, html, wcf, cross-domain

I created a self hosted WCF service which runs on a windows machine. Now I would like to consume the service's operations using AJAX calls. Neither in iExplorer, Firefox nor Chrome I get a resulting JSON stream as supposed to.

What do I have to add to the self hosted service in order to allow cross domain calls?

Regards
Simon

Comment: What binding do you use? How is the WCF service hosted (process? IIS?)

Comment: webHttpBinding, and it is hosted as a service in windows, using ServiceBase.Run(new ioNotificationService());

Answer (score 1):

http://pranayamr.blogspot.se/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html Seems like a valid article. You need to configure your service accordingly. This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Well that article suggest to add [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]. From ASP I assume that the article refers to a web hosted service. My Problem concerns a self hosted service.

Comment: Does someone know the solution for a self hosted service?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add extra methods to expose cross domain policies,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx

Answer (score -1):

For Service GetPerson hosted on localhost\Service.mvc use:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: 'Service.svc/GetPerson', // Location of the service
            data: userid, //Data sent to server
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
            dataType: 'json', //Expected data format from server
            processdata: true, //True or False
            success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call
                alert(data.Name);
            },
            error: function (msg) {// When Service call fails
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Link: http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/1041/complete-example-wcf-ajax-ssl-http

Comment: But does this answer the question about cross Domain calls? I don't think so. If this JQuery code is hosted on a different Domain than the Service, this code will fail, or in other words, your browser will execute the ajax request but wont receive any data. That is my Problem.

Comment: Can you ping from client computer to the server computer? Can you resolve the name (usually by ping <computerName>.<DomainName> ?

If so - put that (<computerName>.<DomainName>) as your URL.

Comment: Yes I can reach the server, the request returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK but no JSON stream is received.

Comment: This seems very strange. Are you sure you are looking at the REST request?
I just use the full computer name in the rest URL, and everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. When I type in the adress of the webservice in the url bar, I get a JSON stream, when I sent a ajax request through an html page, the page does not receive any JSON stream. This is, as I assume, because of the cross domain policy by the browser not allowing ajaw requests to webservices located anywhere else then on the same domain as the calling javascript code. For my webservice on an IIS I could solve this issue by adding a file to the root of the webservice. But for a self hosted webservice installed as a windows service, I'm looking for a new answer.